# how to sum a column in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I am trying to sum a column and get details member wise

My table data is

```
id   membername     cost
1   a               100
2   aa              100
3   a               100
4   aa                0
5   b               100
```

---

In Entity Framework I try to sum cost column and get result like this

```
membername             totalcost
a                      200
aa                     100
b                      100
```

then I am doing this

```
var result = from o in db.pruchasemasters.Where(d => d.memberid == d.membertable.id && d.entrydate >= thisMonthStart && d.entrydate <= thisMonthEnd)
                     group o by new { o.membertable.members } into purchasegroup
                     select new
                     {
                         membername = purchasegroup.Key,
                         total = purchasegroup.Sum(s => s.price)
                     };
```

How do I read the results and is my code right or not?

Comment: An anonymous type is read-only, but what do you mean by "how I read this"?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Something like that will work

```
    var result = db.pruchasemasters.GroupBy(o => o.membername)
                   .Select(g => new { membername = g.Key, total = g.Sum(i => i.cost) });

    foreach (var group in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Membername = {0} Totalcost={1}", group.membername, group.total);
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to do a similar operation but use a Where condition instead of GroupBy? For example, I'm looking to return just membername and total for a single person.

Comment: in my question you can use foreach and get by key.membername and single person also if you put in select

Comment: @AllenWang `db.pruchasemasters.GroupBy(o => "1")...` will generate sql query without the group by