# Linq with join, group and sum not working

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new to Linq and Entity Framework,
below the code and the result that I would like to have.
In there LINQPad works perfectly, but when I bring it to net.core I have this error:

> .Sum(tot => tot.b.Price) could not be translated. Either rewrite the
> query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation
> explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(),
> AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()

Clients
Id - Name
1 - Jhon
2 - Henry
3 - Max

Works
Id - Price - ClientId
1 - 10 - 1
2 - 20 - 2
3 - 30 - 3
4 - 40 - 1
5 - 50 - 2

```
var result = await (from a in dbContext.Clients
                join b in dbContext.Works on a.Id equals b.ClientId
                        where b.Price != 0
                        group new {a, b} by new {a.Name, b.Price} into g
                        select new
                        {
                            Name = g.Key.Name,
                            Total = g.Sum(tot => tot.b.Price)//here is the problem!!!!!!!
                        }).ToListAsync();
```

results:
Jhon    50
Henry   70
Max     30

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message? The translation part or the "switch to client evaluation explicitly" part?

Comment: Why are you grouping by Price.  So only need to group by ClientId.

Comment: What happens if you change `group new {a, b} by new {a.Name, b.Price} into g` to `group b.Price by new a.Name into g` (and refactor the rest of the query)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a difference when you run Linq queries in memory (i.e. on an instance of List class) or on DB with Entity Framework.

In the first case the code is just executed, in the second case the code is translated in a SQL Query. Obviously, not everything is translable.

One solution could be the following:

-Be sure the class "Clients" has a reference to the class "Works", i.e.

```
 public class Clients {
       public string Id {get;set;}
       public string Name {get;set;}
       public IEnumerable<Works> Works {get;set;}
    }
```

-Rewrite your query

```
 var result = await dbContext.Clients.Select(c => new {c.Name, c.Works.Sum(w => w.Price)}).ToListAsync();
```

I suggest to improve the navigation between entities instead of using too complex queries.

EDIT: This solution is not working because no group by is specified.
you may find this post useful: [how to sum a column in entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349573/how-to-sum-a-column-in-entity-framework)

Basically, you need to implement the reverse navigation (i.e. from Works to Clients) in this way

```
public class Works {
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public double Price {get;set;}
    public Clients Client {get;set;}
}
```

and use the following query:

dbContext.Works.GroupBy(w => w.Client.Name).Select(g => new { Client = g.Key, Price = g.Sum(w => w.Price)}).ToListAsync()

Comment: No way!!!! still same error. I.ve checked classes and everything is ok. Could you explain how can I handle this with your suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Here we go!!!!! Finally have made right with your suggestion. I redisigned the model Clients with a list of works and a new field for total. Now everything works great. Should I post the solution? Thanks again. Max

Comment: if it worked could you please mark the answer as correct? Thank you